# as.data.frame of table() to summarize frequencies

Tags: r, dataframe

In **R**, I'm looking for a memory-efficient way to create a summary of tabular data as follows.

Take for example the `data.frame` `foo` which I've used `table()` to summarize, followed by `as.data.frame()` to obtain the frequency counts.

```
foo <- data.frame(x= c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), y=c('ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'fx', 'fy'))
bar <- as.data.frame(table(foo), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

This results in the following frequency count for `bar`

```
   x  y Freq
1  a ab    1
2  b ab    0
3  a ac    1
4  b ac    0
5  a ad    1
6  b ad    0
7  a ae    0
8  b ae    1
9  a fx    0
10 b fx    1
11 a fy    0
12 b fy    1
```

The problem I'm running into is when there are many levels of `x` and `y`, it starts using up significant amounts of memory >64 GB.  I was wondering if there was an alternative way of doing this kind of frequency count.  As a first step, I set `stringsAsFactors=F`, however this doesn't completely solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have this method for fast (sparse) cross tabulation. I think there are possibilities for further optimisation, but it's been good enough for me for large data sets.  The key is the use of `ninteraction` from the `plyr` package to quickly generate a numeric id for each row.

```
tab <- function(df, drop = TRUE) {
  id <- plyr::ninteraction(df)
  ord <- order(id)

  df <- df[ord, , drop = FALSE]
  id <- id[ord]

  freq <- rle(id)$lengths
  labels <- unrowname(df[cumsum(freq), , drop = FALSE])

  data.frame(labels, freq)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `xtabs` method in the `Matrix` package which does sparse cross-tabulation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I think `xtabs` only works with two-ways tables.  It turns out that in my specific case, I actually have a table that's three-ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(foo, ~ x + y, nrow,.drop=FALSE)
```